# Student's t distribution in JavaScript for Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, statistics, google-docs

Google Spreadsheets currently does not support the standard function `TDIST` - i.e. the Student's t-distribution. This function is critical for calculating p-values.

It seems that this is related to the fact that no integral-using functions (AFAICT) are implemented either.

However, Google Docs allows people to add and publish their own scripts, in JavaScript.

So ideally we should have something like:

```
function tdist(t_value, degrees_of_freedom, two_tailed [defaults true]) {...}
```

Anyone know of either an extant implementation of this (my google-fu has not turned up one, but may be weaker than yours) or a good idea for how to do it?

I'd like to publish this together with some other useful functions that are currently calculable but a bit of a pain (like Student's t-test itself).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here you go](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/distributions/tDist.html).

Comment: Oh you sneaky \*\*\*\*\*. :D Beat me to it by half a minute. +1

Comment: Perfect. I've modified it to work w/ Google Docs, take one vs two tailed as argument, and submitted. Hopefully this'll show up in the standard google docs library soon. :)

Comment: @Sai: As of 2012-09-14, from within Google Spreadsheet, pulling down Tools/Script Gallery menu entry, typing in "tdist" into the Search field, one sees an entry of: "Statistical testing functions: tdist(x, dof, onesided) - Student's t-distribution. onesided defaults to false.". Is that your submission?

Comment: @Sai: I determined experimentally that the "tdist" function added to Googles script library gives the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF(x)) while the TDIST function in Excel (tails=1) gives the Complementary Cumulative Distribution Function (CCDF(x)).  I conclude from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function that 1-google_tdist(x,dof,onesided) == excel_tdist(x,dof,1). Compare each using http://www.xuru.org/st/PD.asp so beware those expecting the submitted Google tdist to behave like it does in Excel.

Comment: What's the relation between x-value

Comment: I realise I'm a bit late to the party, but can anyone tell me whether the script behind the link is one-sided/two-sided and what part of the script determines this?

Answer (score 3):

[Google Sheets does now include the `TDIST` function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3295914?hl=en) (if you've switched to the new version).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/distributions/tDist.html - view source.