# Student's T-distribution in C++

Tags: c++, excel, statistics

I need to use the equivalent of Excel's [TINV function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/tinv-function-HP010335663.aspx) in a C++ code with no statistics library linked to it.

The problem is I don't know the maths behind Student's law.

Do you think it will be reasonable to reimplement this function from scratch without using a statistics library?

I don't have access to C++11, in that case I would use [std::student_t_distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/student_t_distribution/).

If yes, please provide me references to code it.

If no, do you know a lightweight library that provides it?

Thank you.

Comment: This kind of thing happens a lot in software development.  Being short of the tools you want to use, you have to make them.  Sorry.  I have had some ask me about a degree in software engineering.  I've always recommended a dual degree.  Software Engineering will show you how to write code but it will not give you the domain knowledge you'll need to accomplish real world tasks.  Given that there are several very good sights on understanding the Student T Distribution. Mathworld.wolfram.com is one of them.  Good luck and may the odds ever be in your favor. :)

Comment: I found this duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709753/students-t-distribution-in-javascript-for-google-spreadsheet
I have two degrees in mathematical engineering and mechanical engineering. It doesn't mean I know everything about maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the lack to this tool means you may have to write one.  I'm already assuming that you looked and could not find one.  The math isn't that bad though. It's just testing to see if two observed distributions have the same mean.  [www.r-tutor.com](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/probability-distributions/student-t-distribution) has a good tutorial on this distribution.  [Math World](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Studentst-Distribution.html) shows the deeper context. Happy hunting.

Comment: I found an implementation in Javascript (50 lines of code). See the duplicate I mentioned in comment to my question.

Comment: Got you.  How does this work from here.  What actions do I need to take?

Comment: View source of the html page. Conversion from Javascript to C/C++ is easy.

Comment: This question stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74874/students-t-distribution should help too.

Comment: There are some assumptions in using the student T distribution.  The problems in using statistics is the assumption must be true for the distribution to be valid.  The first link gives an overview of the assumptions you are making when using the student T distribution. I cannot overstate this (degree in Math and CompSci). Are you sure that you have a some tested values for distribution in your sets.  The first link will give you some small understanding in this.

Comment: The Javascript page actually gives the inverse function of what Excel provides. I still need an algorithm. :)

Comment: What I need is to calculate a quantile which is not an easy task according to this page http://analyse-it.com/blog/2013/2/quantiles-percentiles-why-so-many-ways-to-calculate-them. Apparently Excel uses the R-7 algorithm to invert the t-distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Boost has a math library with statistics functions. Here is an example on how to use it for the student's t-test
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/stat_tut/weg/st_eg/two_sample_students_t.html

Comment: Cool. Have you seen anything like this for C#?

Comment: @garaber ExtremeOptimization has C# implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's too much work without using a statistics library.

What I am gonna do is generate numeric values in Excel for the range of values I need and copy it in an array in my code.

Hardcore style.

Comment: you made reference to a student t distribution.  You will have to make sure that the data you generate will fall into that distribution.  The distribution becomes your check